# How can I change text to input field clicking on the text itself

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change commitment text to be changed with input field when I click on commitment and when I press enter it should show the newly entered input.

I am new to javascript but I looked many codes but they didn't slove what I want please can you provide any idea how to do this?`

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="dtBasicExample" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <!-- Table head -->
      <thead class="theader">
        <tr>
          <th>Grade</th>
          <th>Student</th>
          <th>
            <!-- Default un -->
            <!-- <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="tableDefaultCheck1">
              <label class="custom-control-label" for="tableDefaultCheck1">P/A</label>
            </div> -->P/A
          </th>
          <th>Check-In</th>
          <th>Check-Out</th>
          <th>Tutor</th>
          <th>Videos</th>
          <th>Others</th>
          <th>Commitment</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
<tbody>
</tr>
        <tr>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>Name</td>
          <th scope="row">
            <!-- Default un -->
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="tableDefaultCheck3">
              <label class="custom-control-label" for="tableDefaultCheck3"></label>
            </div>
          </th>
          <td>Time</td>
          <td>Time</td>
          <td>Time</td>
          <td>Time</td>
          <td>Time</td>
          <td>Commitment
            <div class="md-form">
              <input type="text" id="form2" class="form-control">
              <label for="form2">New Commitment</label>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
$('.md-form input').keydown(function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 13 && $(this).val().length > 0){
    $(this).next().text($(this).val())
  }
});
```

**Working demo**

```js
$('.md-form input').keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13 && $(this).val().length > 0) {
    $(this).next().show().text($(this).val())
    $(this).hide();
  }
});

$('.Commitment label').click(function() {
  $(this).prev().show();
  $(this).hide();
})
```

```css
.Commitment input {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="dtBasicExample" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <!-- Table head -->
    <thead class="theader">
      <tr>
        <th>Grade</th>
        <th>Student</th>
        <th>
          <!-- Default un -->
          <!-- <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="tableDefaultCheck1">
              <label class="custom-control-label" for="tableDefaultCheck1">P/A</label>
            </div> -->P/A
        </th>
        <th>Check-In</th>
        <th>Check-Out</th>
        <th>Tutor</th>
        <th>Videos</th>
        <th>Others</th>
        <th>Commitment</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <th scope="row">
          <!-- Default un -->
          <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="tableDefaultCheck3">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="tableDefaultCheck3"></label>
          </div>
        </th>
        <td>Time</td>
        <td>Time</td>
        <td>Time</td>
        <td>Time</td>
        <td>Time</td>
        <td class="Commitment">
          <div class="md-form">
            <input type="text" id="form2" class="form-control">
            <label for="form2">New Commitment</label>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <th scope="row">
          <!-- Default un -->
          <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="tableDefaultCheck3">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="tableDefaultCheck3"></label>
          </div>
        </th>
        <td>Time</td>
        <td>Time</td>
        <td>Time</td>
        <td>Time</td>
        <td>Time</td>
        <td class="Commitment">
          <div class="md-form">
            <input type="text" id="form2" class="form-control">
            <label for="form2">New Commitment</label>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help...But I want little bit different...like when I click on the text commitment it should open an input field and should overwrite the old text with new one...

Comment: @RahulDewangan Try run the demo now

Comment: But one problem is still there I am using MDbootstrap which has it's own js library and you used cdnjs library both are clashing, means not working properly when both are used...

Comment: If you have a jQuery library already installed use that, My example only use this because it's available in the snippet tool.

Comment: From what I can see MDbootstrapper uses the latest version of jQuery, same as the one i use.

Comment: My version is 3.4.1

Comment: Then you should be fine with the code I wrote. updated the demo to 3.4.1

Comment: @RahulDewangan To close out this question, please accept Carten's answer as correct by clicking the checkbox at top left of answer. I'll upvote the answer for you. Good job, gentlemen.